# How to lazy load images with picture element in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, lazy-loading

I would like to lazy load the images in my Angular 4 project. I am using the `picture` element to show images in the project. I have seen and tried few lazy loading packages in Angular. Here are they
[ng-lazyload-image](https://github.com/tjoskar/ng-lazyload-image), [ng2-image-lazy-load](https://github.com/NathanWalker/ng2-image-lazy-load) and [ng-lazy-load](https://github.com/greg-md/ng-lazy-load).

But none of the packages mention, how to lazy load picture element as it contains many source elements.

Here's the schema of my `picture` element:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="image-1x.webp 1x, image-2x.webp 2x" type="image/webp"/>
    <source srcset="image-1x.png 1x, image-2x.png 2x" type="image/png"/>
    <img src="image-1x.png" alt="some text">
</picture>
```

Please help me sort out this issue.